# User validation before phone authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, real-time

I want to validate user phone number  exists in Firebase before phone authentication. And if user exists then only OTP verification will start otherwise show error. Kindly help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Admin SDK to lookup a user by `phoneNumber`:
`admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)`

This will help you check if a user record with this phone number already exists.

Learn more by visiting the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data).

You can create an HTTP endpoint to do so.

Comment: I have created a firebase real-time Database and now i want to make a calendar activity and call the data i have entered in database in calender....help me out please

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make restrict user base by entering from admin panel.?
If so then use anonymous authentication for reading the database if the entered no. exists in database then only continue phone auth and link these anonymous and phone account.

Comment: i want that user phone number is identified in firebase first and then the phone authentication activity will start

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class PhoneNumberAuthentication extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // already signed in
        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneNumberAuthentication.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        // not signed in
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(
                                Arrays.asList(
                                          new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build())).build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        // Successfully signed in
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(new Intent(PhoneNumberAuthentication.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                // User pressed back button
                //showSnackbar(R.string.sign_in_cancelled);
                return;
            }

            if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                // showSnackbar(R.string.no_internet_connection);
                return;
            }

            // showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_error);
            // Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in error: ", response.getError());
        }
    }
}}
```

also add build.gradle

```
  implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
```

Comment: I guess this is just a implementation of UserPhoneAuthentication via FirebaseUI there is no logic for checking whether user exists in the DB or not just delete this answer

Comment: i want to grant access to next activity after checking user  contact exists in firebase. help me out please....

Comment: I have created an app in fire store and i want to check the user number exists in firestore .I want the Rules which i can apply in firestore real-time database to do so.Kindly help me out with  the rules please........